# Need to display the vet number when the number of consultations by the vet is greater than 1

Tags: sql

SELECT vetno, COUNT(vetno) AS NumberOfConsultations FROM consultation GROUP BY vetno ;

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query, when ever you aggregate and you wanted to filter out using aggregated column, you have to use **having** clause

```
SELECT vetno, COUNT(vetno) AS NumberOfConsultations FROM consultation GROUP BY vetno having  COUNT(vetno) > 1;
```